# WPDB: cannot create multiple database tables with plugin installation

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My plugin is supposed to create two tables upon activation. However only the second table is created. Here is the part of my function that creates the tables.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
global $wpdb;
$ml_wpid = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_wpid";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $ml_wpid . " (
    `wp_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL
    `name` text NOT NULL
UNIQUE (`char_id`)
) $charset_collate;";
dbDelta( $sql );

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
global $wpdb;
$ml_char = $wpdb->prefix . "ml_char";
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $ml_char . " (
    `char_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (`char_id`)
) $charset_collate;";
dbDelta( $sql );

// starts output buffering
ob_start();
```

I feel that the reason this is happening is because the $sql variable is being redefined. However I've tried renaming the second table's $sql variable to something different like $sql2 but nothing different happened. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue my first table works but the second does not.

```
function Create_Tables_Super_Farm()
{

global $wpdb;

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

// Calendar Events
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "calendarevents"; 
$table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "changelogs"; 
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timestamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  TypeID int(11) NOT NULL,
  CustomerID int(11) NOT NULL,
  SeedID int(11) NOT NULL,
  Date datetime NOT NULL,
  Title varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  Description varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY ID_UNIQUE (ID)
) $charset_collate ;";
$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name2 (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timestamp datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  EmployeeID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  TableID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  Table varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  Field varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  Before varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  After varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY ID_UNIQUE (ID)
) $charset_collate ;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
dbDelta( $sql2 );
}
```

Try removing the "`" char's I could not get anything to work before I did that.
Overwriting the $sql variable should not cause an issue. Best I can tell dbDelta is very finicky and I am missing a space or something. Can not find it so far any help would be great.